# How to Extend Root partition from left?

Tags: filesystem, root, drive, file-format, data-loss

[337gbs to the left of root drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDigW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QFkd.png)
I have windows on the left partition and resized the remaining drive space to add to the Linux root file system but not sure how to rearrange and add on the root partition.